# Dynamic element doesn't respond on call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu and when I click a button to add a item to another item( to be a submenu) the item/parent doesn't respond to the jQuery code for the parent items.

```js
$('.menu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function() {
  alert("Working");
});

$(".test").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).after("<ul></ul>");
  $(this).parent().addClass("has-sub");
  $(this).parent().find("ul").append("<li><a href='#'>SubItem</a></li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="test">Item</a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Item</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SubItem</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$("body").on('click',".test",function(event) {})
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(".test").on('click',function(event) {})
```

```js
$('.menu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function() {
  alert("Working");
});

$(".test").on('click',function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if($(this).parent().find("ul").length == 0) {
  $(this).after("<ul></ul>");
  $(this).parent().addClass("has-sub");
  }
  $(this).parent().find("ul").append("<li><a href='#'>SubItem</a></li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="test">Item</a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Item</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SubItem</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```